# VBA. Retrieve text from other application

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to retrieve text from another application, and is just returning 3 blank spaces.
(This is strongly inspired by http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/02/02/vbavb-netvb6click-opensavecancel-button-on-ie-download-window-part-ii/)

```
Ret = FindWindow(vbNullString, "koelskerN - R1Q2 b4449 (port 27910)")

If Ret <> 0 Then
    ChildRet = FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)

    strBuff = String(GetWindowTextLength(ChildRet) + 1, Chr$(0))
    GetWindowText ChildRet, strBuff, Len(strBuff)
    ButCap = strBuff

    debug.print strBuff 'Is just returning 3. blank spaces)
End If
```

[image: Spy++ and application]

Ret returns = 8062086
ChildRet returns = 9309970

I haven't really tried using FindWindow before, so I'd appreciate some guidelines, on how to extract text from within and edit-class.

Comment: Using @SiddharthRout example, you can click in this edit box, then you can simply `SendKeys` to `Copy` the text in clipboard and then read from the memory.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that the application had a logfile 1, which extracts everything to a .txt-file. This question is solved.